# jQuery variable containing selector not working as expected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide a section of the page using jQuery and Bootstrap Switch Plugin. I have the following code.

```
jQuery("[name='toggle-show-hide']").on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr("data-wrapper-class");
    console.log(id)
    jQuery('.column-'+id+' .finished-reading').hide( "slow" );
    console.log ('.column-'+id+' .finished-reading')
});
```

In the console, I am getting the proper `id` as well as the selector which in one case is `.column-56 .finished-reading`. Howevere, the `.hide()` is not working i.e `div.column-56 .finished-reading` doesn't hide.

Here is the HTML markup.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 column-56">
    <div class="col-xs-12 column-56-header"><input type="checkbox" name="toggle-show-hide" data-size="mini" checked="checked" data-label-text="Show Read" data-wrapper-class="56"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 finished-reading">I'm done with this.. So hide!</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">I'm not done with this.. So show!</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">I'm not done with this.. So show!</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/epnbgbLm/

Comment: could you put this in a jsfiddle

Comment: @Todd, sure. Just gimme a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

also, i got the namespaced event to work out.

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/5406b1271734fded3f08b081e8f713f6)

[image: switch]

```
$(function() {
  var $switch = $('[name="toggle-show-hide"]');
  
  $switch.bootstrapSwitch();
  
  $switch.on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(e, state) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-wrapper-class");

    $('.column-'+id+' .finished-reading')[state ? 'hide': 'show']("slow");
  });
  
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did before you posted the answer. i got the idea when @sean9999 posted his answer. I was missing `event, state` in the function.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work when you change the event handler to `change`

```
jQuery("[name='toggle-show-hide']").on('change', function() { ... }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sean9999/h9e77sca/4/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not because of jquery !

You are listening to a event `switchChange.bootstrapSwitch` which is not been trigger.

Changing the event name from 'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch' to 'change'/'click'

```
jQuery("[name='toggle-show-hide']").on('change', function() { ... }
```